# Ajax append one row instead of array

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax function that gets an array of data from the backend and when I try to append those data in the blade it only shows 1 row instead of an array of rows.

## Issues

1. Only 1 row append by ajax
2. Select option will be empty when results return while I don't have any code to clear my select option.

## Code

```
$(function() {
            // get cities
            $('#province').on('change', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
                });

                var hospitalId = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('hospitals') }}/'+encodeURI(hospitalId),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('dd: ', data.data);
                        if(data.data != null) {
                            $('.resError').hide();
                            $('.result').show();
                            // data to append
                            $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                                $('#code').html(value.code);
                                $('#name').html(value.name);
                                $('#type').html(value.type);
                                $('#class').html(value.class);
                                $('#beds').html(value.beds);
                                $('#owner').html(value.owner);
                                $('#province').html(value.province);
                                $('#city').html(value.city);
                                $('#address').html(value.address);
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('.resError').show();
                            $('.result').hide();
                            $('.resError').html('something went wrong, try again!');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(err) {
                        $('.resError').show();
                        $('.resError').html('You need to select province!');
                        $('.result').hide();
                        $('#code').html('');
                        $('#name').html('');
                        $('#type').html('');
                        $('#class').html('');
                        $('#beds').html('');
                        $('#owner').html('');
                        $('#province').html('');
                        $('#city').html('');
                        $('#address').html('');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

`results`

[image: one]

## Update

```
<p>Results</p>
<div class="resError clearfix mt-4" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="result clearfix mt-4" style="display:none;">
    <table class="mb-3 table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>​​​
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Code</th>
                <td id="code"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Name</th>
                <td id="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Type</th>
                <td id="type"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Class</th>
                <td id="class"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Beds</th>
                <td id="beds"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Owner</th>
                <td id="owner"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Province</th>
                <td id="province"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">City</th>
                <td id="city"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Address</th>
                <td id="address"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#code').html(value.code);` to `$('#code').append(value.code);`  but u need to append root div not like this

Comment: may i see you html where you are appending so  i can give you proper solution of this

Comment: sure i'll add it.

Comment: @KamleshPaul updated

Comment: okay. got it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in blade

```php
<p>Results</p>
<div class="resError clearfix mt-4" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="result clearfix mt-4" style="display:none;">
    <table class="mb-3 table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody id="body">​​​
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

in javascript

```js
$.each(data.data, function(key, value) {

    var element = `
    <tr>
            <th width="50">Code</th>
                <td id="code">${value.code}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Name</th>
                <td id="name">${value.name}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Type</th>
                <td id="type">${value.type}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Class</th>
                <td id="class">${value.class}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Beds</th>
                <td id="beds">${value.beds}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Owner</th>
                <td id="owner">${value.owner}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Province</th>
                <td id="province">${value.province}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">City</th>
                <td id="city">${value.city}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="50">Address</th>
                <td id="address">${value.address}</td>
            </tr>
    `;

    $('#body')append(element);

});
```

Comment: thank you it does work however it doesn't include `mb-3` class from `<table...` which was to separate tables, this only create rows inside 1 table

Answer (score 0):

In your below code, you are appending value by the fieldId, that's why it is only appending only the last row(each iteration, the value is being updated in background) values are being set.

```
  $('#code').html(value.code);
    $('#name').html(value.name);
    $('#type').html(value.type);
    $('#class').html(value.class);
    $('#beds').html(value.beds);
    $('#owner').html(value.owner);
    $('#province').html(value.province);
    $('#city').html(value.city);
    $('#address').html(value.address);
```

So, to achieve your purpose, you have to append these as a complete row and insert into the table, not just appending fieldwise value but rowwise and insert that row into the table. I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are always changing the same elements of the same table. I think you will need to append one table per row:

```js
$.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
  $(".result").append('<table class="mb-3 table table-bordered table-hover">...</table>') 
});
```

However, you may want to use Handlebars or some other templating library to avoid creating a long string with the table.